# Neo4j: Avoiding Sub Paths to be Returned

Tags: neo4j

I have this simple case:

```
CREATE
(P1:Person { fullname:'John Smith' }),
(P2:Person { fullname:'Mark Almond'}),
(P3:Person { fullname:'Mark Twain'})

CREATE
(P1)-[:Friend]->(P2),
(P2)-[:Friend]->(P3)
```

When I run the following query:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*0..2]-()
WHERE ID(a) = 0 // john smith id
RETURN *
```

I get the right graph displayed.

However when I see the returned "rows", it displays:

```
╒══════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╕
│a                     │p                             │
╞══════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════╡
│{fullname: John Smith}│[{fullname: John Smith}]      │
├──────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│{fullname: John Smith}│[{fullname: John Smith}, {}, {│
│                      │fullname: Mark Almond}]       │
├──────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│{fullname: John Smith}│[{fullname: John Smith}, {}, {│
│                      │fullname: Mark Almond}, {}, {f│
│                      │ullname: Mark Twain}]         │
└──────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

is there a way to get only the longest path only, and not the other "combinatory" paths with 1 or 2 elements?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for longest paths:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*0..2]-()
WHERE ID(a) = 0 // john smith id
WITH a, p ORDER by length(p) desc LIMIT 1
RETURN *
```

In case the path specification uses a direction (e.g. only outgoing relationships) you can use instead:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*0..2]->(e)
WHERE ID(a) = 0 // john smith id
   AND NOT (e)-->()  // no further outgoing rels from end node
RETURN *
```

Comment: I am using your first solution that is ok (but my set up was too simple).for one path and one case. The problem comes when I have multiple long paths for the same node. So the order/limit trick it won't work (Image I add another friend to John Smith not related to any of the others) as I need all the paths.